# UIScrollView inside a CALayer

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, calayer

I'm developing some kind of card game in which my view objects (cards, etc) are all  CALayers. These objects are added as sublayers of a `mainBoard` (a CALayer), which, in turn, is a sublayer of the `[UIView layer]` property of my `mainView`. Everything is Ok, I can do hit testing to verify which layer is being touched through the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` callback of the `mainView` class normally, and so on.

However, I need to have a scroll inside my `mainBoard` to show "bigger" CALayers, so I tried first adding the "bigger" CALayer inside a `CAScrollLayer`, but I noticed that the `CAScrollLayer` doesn't really scroll (doesn't handle user input, neither draws scrollbars). So, the workaround would be to add an UIScrollView directly to the `mainView` UIView. The `UIScrollView` scrolls perfectly, until I try to add the "bigger" layer to it, by using `[scrollView.layer addSublayer:<bigger layer>]`.

Does anyone has any idea of how I can have "scrollable" objects inside a CALayer?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly happens when adding big layers to the scrollview?, Besides I think adding sublayer directly to scrollView.layer is not a good idea, why don't you add them to a layer of a view contained by your scrollview?

Comment: Can you define what the "bigger" CALayers are? Can you briefly describe why the "bigger" items must be CALayers? By reading your question, I wonder why you are not keeping it simple and just using UIScrollView - it has everything you've asked for, which would be better to not re-implement.

Comment: My whole application consists of CALayers objects because I'm working in Core Animation level instead of UIKit abstraction level. The problem is that the Core Animation doesn't provide a Scrollable component, so I had to do a workaround mixing UIKit objects (UIScrollView) and CoreAnimation objects (CALayers) and making them working seamlessly. This is not a problem since UIKit is just a wrapper for CoreAnimation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nacho4d pointed the answer for my question.
Replying to mark: the "bigger" layer (a layer whose bounds is bigger than the area available in the screen (and so, needs to be contained in a scrollable area)).

The solution was to first wrap the "bigger" layer in a UIView:

```
UIView *wrapperView = ...
[wrapperView.layer addSublayer:<bigger_layer>];
```

afterwards, I can add the view as a subview of the UIScrollview:

```
[<uiscrollview> addSubview:wrapperView];

// set up scrolling properties
<uiscrollview>.contentSize = <bigger_layer>.frame.size;
```

The problem was that I was trying to add the "bigger" layer as a sublayer of the UIScrollview directly, instead, wrapping it in a UIView and adding it as a subview worked.

Thanks